# Concept clarity - wavelet tree

Tags: c++, string, tree, compression, string-algorithm

How a wavelet tree can be used for storing integer-ids. Say for example integer-ids collection be (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). Could any one explain how it works?

General wavelet tree construction looks like [this](http://alexbowe.com/wavelet-trees/) for a string. But how integers can be stored in a wavelet tree ?

Comment: You consider each number as separated alphabet char ?

Comment: that could make sense right ? I want to know is it the way how to approach this ?